# Record audio using HTML5 Microphone?

Tags: html, audio

Is it possible in any current browser (including, for instance, Chrome Canary)?

All the working examples I've seen are speech-to-text.  Is there anything to either record audio or stream it to a server?

**Update 4/30/2012:**
The getUserMedia API is sloowwwwly [making its way into browsers](http://caniuse.com/stream).  It is in the latest version of Opera and apparently [is in-progress in Chromium](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118881).

If you want a taste of how it will work, see: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: The support has finally arrived, you may follow the documentation on http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/09/Live-Web-Audio-Input-Enabled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an implementation of this in current browsers.

There is a JavaScript API for getting access to microphone and camera planned:
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/video-conferencing-and-peer-to-peer-communication.html#obtaining-local-multimedia-content

Also, have a look at this question:
[How do I access navigator.getUserMedia()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845306/how-do-i-access-navigator-getusermedia)

Comment: This link is based on the pre-spec, not on any current implementations

Answer (score 0):

The standard versions of Chrome and Firefox fully support navigator.getUserMedia();

Numerous examples have been already made to record audio directly in the browser, in several formats even.

Here are a few examples:
This is a fully oriented project towards testing the limits and possibilities of the current state of webRTC
https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/

I've personally made a record to mp3 library in JS sources can be found here:
https://github.com/nusofthq/Recordmp3js

Also for updates you can check the latest MediaStream Recording API proposal by the Media Capture Task Force. This is not yet implemented in the current browsers but it will in the near future.