# Access camera and photo library via html5

Tags: php, javascript, html, safari

I would like to know if there's a way to access the camera and photo library without phone gap. Pure js and html5 or php.

Thanks,

Comment: What camera and photo library? On what kind of a device?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845306/how-do-i-access-navigator-getusermedia

Comment: thanks for the response, but it doesn't said anything about safari...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make an educated guess and say that you'll need some kind of middle-ware to go between the phone and the browser. HTML/JavaScript disallows accessing things like the file system of a device. This is part of the security.

Comment: Now is possible via safari iOS6 : )