# Communicate with a camera directly in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, camera, webcam

Is it possible to communicate with a camera directly in pure JavaScript (no library like jQuery)?

If yes, what is the most simple pure javascript code to do that?

Comment: No, it's not. You need a plug-in based solution such as flash or an applet.

Comment: 1. What technology you're using desktop/browser/mobile/etc? 2. What have you tried? BTW, jQuery isn't a plugin but a library

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a webcam with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922723/using-a-webcam-with-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getUserMedia`  is available in preview builds of all browsers.

[How do I access navigator.getUserMedia()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845306/how-do-i-access-navigator-getusermedia)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't posible to do that using pure Javascript (I believe it will be possible soon), but I know it can be done using Flash or Java applets.

Answer (score -1):

Not possible on client-side JavaScript with any technology I know of. It'd be a security violation to allow such a thing. You'll need to use Flash, Java, Silverlight or some other form of browser plugin. However, you can interact with a Flash object using JavaScript.

There's a nice tutorial about using a webcam in Flash / AS3 here: http://theflashstudioblog.blogspot.com/2010/10/capturing-webcam-input-with.html