# How do I utilize the computer's camera in HTML5?

Tags: html, camera

I have a Flash app that I'm looking to port into HTML5. The app allows the user to take photo of themselves and then gives them some Bitmaps to overlay, scale, position over their face (like a beard or whatnot) and then saves the newly produced image out to a PHP listener.

I wrote the original, so, I can port the bulk of it pretty easily, but have no idea how HTML5 tackles the usage of the computer's camera and can't seem to find anything online that points to this.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: HTML5 doesn't have an API for a camera.  Are you doing this for mobile devices or any device?  You may find this useful: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10920

Comment: This question seems to have interesting background info--it's not clear to me whether this functionality has yet been standardized or otherwise implemented *across* HTML5-compliant browsers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845306/how-do-i-access-navigator-getusermedia

Comment: ah... pity, guess I'll have to wait a while to make this jump.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a W3C Device API that will allow capturing data from the camera. However, I am not aware of any browser supporting it. This appears to be a future implementation. But, one I think will become reality soon since Adobe just gave Flex to Apache http://incubator.apache.org/flex/.

Once the Device API is implemented, it will be accessed via `getUserMedia`. To see where they are in completing the spec, take a look at the public mailing archive: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-media-capture/

More can be learned here: http://www.w3.org/2009/dap/

Comment: Opera at least has experimental builds. http://my.opera.com/desktopteam/blog/2012/01/10/camera-and-privacy-changes-in-labs

Answer (score 1):

i dont think a camera api is exposed to html5. You will need to use a flash or silverlight shim.

Comment: yeah... unfortunately, if I'm going the Flash route, I have no reason to move to HTML5 at all then.  The app is already IN Flash, the point here was to make it accessible to iOS devices (without writing an iOS native app).

Comment: i can recommend using PhoneGap if you use the native approach you can code it in html and then leverage the native camera api via phonegap. You will still need to release through the app store though.

Comment: yeah... sadly the app store is not an option, this has to be a 100% web app.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you will need a small flash app to access the web cam, and expose that data via the HTML5 canvas.

Here is a lightweight jquery plugin:
http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/